# Does California tax personal K-1 income from an out-of-state partnership?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, california, general-partnership, schedule-k-1

As a resident of California, if I get a K-1 from Connecticut, do I have to pay income taxes on this income for my California return?

Using Turbo Tax, the answer seems to be no, since there was no California K-1, but I want to make sure I have not entered something wrong because I was expecting it to be taxed with a credit for any Connecticut taxes paid on this income.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

California taxes worldwide income of its residents. So it doesn't matter if your K-1 is from California or from Connecticut if you're a California resident. Your expectation seems to be correct. State taxes are often the weak point for these programs, especially California which has quite complicated tax laws.

If in doubt - get a CA licensed tax preparer ([CRTP](http://www.ctec.org/Content.aspx?pid=10)), CPA or EA to help you with your tax return. Tax preparers in California *must* be licensed by the State unless they hold a [EA](http://www.irs.gov/Tax-Professionals/Enrolled-Agents/Enrolled-Agent-Information) license from the IRS.